# MySQL connection error with Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I get the following error when I run the Django command "python manage.py syncdb"

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I have installed python, django and py26-mysql using macports. I ran in to issues installing mysql through macports so I installed a standalone version.

What do I need to change so that django uses my standalone version of mysql and not macports version of mysql. I have verified that only standalone server is running when I execute this command.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`HOST` setting](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#host) in your settings file:

```
"HOST": '/path/to/your/socket.sock'
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the following and it worked

    "HOST": '127.0.0.1'

Comment: This took me a while to figure out - thanks for making it easier ;-)